# Guardar valor de uma variável em laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou iniciando um projeto em Laravel, e na sidebar tenho uma dropdow  com uma lista na qual eu acesso o banco de dados e trago a informação de 3 empresas por exemplo, e quando eu clicar em uma dessas empresas, gostaria de guardar o valor do id para que eu possa utilizar esse valor para inserir no banco juntamente com um insert ou update em outro cadastro, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Método Controller:

```
public static function emitentes(){
    $users = User::where('id', 1)->with('emitentes')->get()->first();
    $emp_user = $users->emitentes;
    return $emp_user;
}
```

Bloco PHP requisitando as infomações:

```
             @php

                use App\Http\Controllers\EmitenteController;
                use App\Models\Cliente;

                $empresas = EmitenteController::emitentes();

            @endphp
```

Código da Dropdow:

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">

                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-university"></i>
                    <span class="label label-warning">{{count($empresas)}}</span>
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li class="header">Você pode emitir recibo para {{count($empresas)}} empresas</li>

                    <li>

                        <ul class="menu">

                            @foreach($empresas as $e)
                                <li><!-- start notification -->
                                    <a href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-industry text-aqua"></i> {{$e->name}}
                                </a>
                            </li><!-- end notification -->
                            @endforeach

                        </ul>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>
```

Imagem de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como dar mais detalhes?! Não deu pra entender muito bem. O que você já fez?

Comment: Veja se ajudou? eu gostaria de armazenar esse valor do id da empresa quando eu clicar em um dos itens da lista... pra mim utilizar mais tarde, se possivel colocar um icone com a cor diferente no qual eu selecionar..

Comment: Só PHP mesmo, nada de Javascript?!

Comment: Mas você diz "usar mais tarde" quer dizer mesmo depois de navegar em outras partes do site/sistema?

Comment: Eu gostaria que fosse em php mas acho que javascript também daria, acho que o importante é eu conseguir utilizar o id!

Comment: Sim, seria possível? não conseguir utilizar variável de sessão... nao sei como o laravel se comporta

Comment: Você pode salvar o id nos cookies. Já experimentou fazer isso?

Comment: Não tentei! como eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com **PHP**, uma opção seria salvar o `id` nos *cookies* usando a função [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php). Exemplo:

```
setcookie("empresa_id", '15');
```

Para resgatar o valor do *cookie* que está salvo, basta usar `$_COOKIE`. Veja:

```
echo $_COOKIE["empresa_id"];
```

O próprio Laravel possui alguns recursos também para esse mesmo proprósito. Veja aqui na documentação [sobre *Requests & Input*](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies).

Com **Javavascript**, também é possível fazer com *cookies*, mas se preferir pode usar usar [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage). Veja um exemplo:

```
// Atribui um valor a empresa_id em relação a empresa com valor 15
window.localStorage.setItem('empresa_id', '15');

// Resgata o empresa_id 
var usuario = window.localStorage.getItem('empresa_id');

// Remove o empresa_id 
window.localStorage.removeItem('empresa_id');
```

Comment: Em Javascript funcionou!! obrigado..

Comment: @UlissesGimenes com cookies você tentou?! ou descartou?!

Comment: Beleza! Precisar, estamos por aqui! o/

Comment: Com cokies eu não consegui, funcionou apenas com o javascript

Comment: inclusive não estou conseguindo fazer parte do que eu queria, se puder me ajudar.... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229736/trecho-de-javascrip-n%C3%A3o-funciona