# Trecho de Javascript não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, talvez possa até ser coisa simples, mas não me dá o resultado esperado

Na criação do componente html:

```
 <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">

                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-university"></i>
                    <span class="label label-warning">{{count($empresas)}}</span>
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li class="header">Você pode emitir recibo para {{count($empresas)}} empresas</li>

                    <li>

                        <ul class="menu">

                            @foreach($empresas as $e)
                                <li><!-- start notification -->
                                    <a name="itemlista" id="{{$e->id}}"
                                       onclick="guardaIdSplit({{$e->id.":".$e->name}})" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-industry text-aqua"></i> {{$e->name}}
                                </a>
                            </li><!-- end notification -->
                            @endforeach

                        </ul>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>
```

No script:

```
 function guardaIdSplit(empresa) {

                    var newArray = empresa.split(":");

                    var id = newArray[0];
                    var name = newArray[1];

                    $("[name=itemlista]").removeClass("text-green");
                    $("[name=itemlista]").addClass("text-black");

                    window.localStorage.setItem('emitente_id', id);

                    $("#" + id).removeClass("text-aqua");
                    $("#" + id).addClass("text-green");

                    $("#emitenteSelect").text(""+name);

                }
```

Deveria ser próximo dessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas qual problema ocorre? Não executa? Aparece alguma msg de erro no console?

Comment: Dentro do trecho tinha colocado até um alert e não executa, não sei porque... ao lado do dropdow era para preencher o nome da empresa... so para mostrar a empresa selecionada..

Comment: e não acontece nada

Comment: O trecho esta da forma correta as variaveis, o array e tudo mais? passei dessa forma no onclick="guardaIdSplit({{$e->id.":".$e->name}})"

Comment: Quando clico na casinha eu escolho uma empresa na lista e ele deveria alterar onde está microsoft para a empresa selecionada!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função JS está sem falhas de sintaxe, então o problema é provavelmente na chamada. Analisando pelo que você colocou acima:

Seu código: `onclick="guardaIdSplit({{$e->id.":".$e->name}})"`

Deve renderizar: `onclick="guardaIdSplit(1:Teste)"`

Sendo que deveria passar uma String: `onclick="guardaIdSplit('1:Teste')"`

Portando a solução deve ser: `onclick="guardaIdSplit('{{$e->id.":".$e->name}}')"`

Comment: Muito obrigado, não tinha visto essa questão!!

Comment: Como é que eu consigo fazer com que esse método de guardaIdSplit seja executado, de forma com que ele pegue o primeiro elemento da lista? sem que o usuário vá lá no dropdow e escolha um item..Apenas para fins de inicialização..

Comment: Até quando eu consigo utilizar o valor da variável neste método window.localStorage.setItem('emitente_id', id), ou seja até quando ela fica disponível... por exemplo se eu clicar em um link que mostre uma lista e atualiza a página, eu perco o valor dessa variável?